# AngularJS - Does JQuery UI work with the built in JQLite

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jqlite

According to the *[AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)*, *[JQLite](https://gist.github.com/esfand/9638882)* is already a part of a base *[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)* package.

Does this mean I can include *[JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/)* with the *[JQLite](https://gist.github.com/esfand/9638882)* built into *[AnuglarJS](https://angularjs.org/)*? Or do I specifically have to use the full *[JQuery](https://jquery.com/)* install?

Comment: Don't use jquery (and by extension jquery-ui) with Angular. They are both DOM manipulation frameworks and will not work well together causing you countless hours of troubleshooting all kinds of vague little issues.

Comment: @Lex I agree with you... but I need proof of these vague little issues to make an argument to the team

Comment: In that case as long as you are aware of potential issues, I believe you will need the full jquery library and not the jqlite included with Angular.

Comment: @Lex That would be my guess. I see nowhere in the JQuery UI documentation that you can use JQLite instead of JQuery

Answer (score 0):

There are many articles addressing specifically this question, but [this one answers a lot](https://www.quora.com/Why-we-should-not-use-jQuery-in-AngularJS)

That being said, as long as you know what you're doing, you should be fine imo.

Comment: The only problem I have with you answer is that it does not address JQuery UI specifically. JQuery UI is a totally different library than JQuery...